# How to extract zip file in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I am running the latest Laravel 6 and wanting to upload and extract a ZIP file. I tried using the composer chumper/zipper - but seems it not compatible with Laravel 6 yet. So I am trying to use PHP zipArchive.

My code for the proccess I am trying is:

```
                    $docfileext1 =  $request->file('czipfile')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $random_filename1 = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123"), -5);
                $newfilename1 = $random_filename1.'.'.$docfileext1;
                //First check this is a ZIP file
                if ($docfileext1 <> 'zip') {
                    return back(); //->witherrors('this is not a ZIP file. Please select a zip file');
                }

                $request->file('czipfile')->move(
                    base_path() . '/storage/app/'.$oid.'/courses/'.$inscourse, $newfilename1
                );

                //Now unzip
                $target_path = base_path() . '/storage/app/' .$oid. '/courses/'. $inscourse.'/'.$newfilename1;              
                $extract_path = base_path() . '/storage/app/' .$oid. '/courses/'. $inscourse.'/';


                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $x = $zip->open($target_path);
                if ($x === true) {
                    $zip->extractTo($extract_path);
                    $zip->close();
                }
```

The zip IS succesfully uploading to the correct location.

example of $target_path is `/var/www/html/project/storage/app/1/courses/1/random.zip`

However, I get an error:

> SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for /tmp/php59z5uT

I have checked the php.ini file and the sizes and memory are way higher than the 700kb test zip file I am trying to use.

Which is popping up when I hit the `$zip->open` function.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here OR is there a better way? Sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for this too and I found this method, I'm not an expert but this does the job

using : [vipsoft/unzip](https://github.com/vipsoft/unzip)

my code was like this

```
if(isset($request->zipfile)){
   $unzipper  = new Unzip();
   $file = $request->zipfile->store('public'); //store file in storage/app/zip
   $filenames = $unzipper->extract(storage_path('app/'.$file),storage_path('app/public'));
   //extract the files in storage/app/public 
   dd($filenames); //show file names
}
```

I hope this was helpful